# maven deployin working from command line but not in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

so, as the title suggests, I've tried several times deploying a maven test project from eclipse to a nexus repository, and all i got is the Error code 401, Unauthorized. Otherwise, if i run the deploy command `mvn deploy` from command line, the build works just fine and if i search for the snasphots i'm trying to upload in the nexus repository, it's just where it should be, in the proper folder.

Any suggestions why this occurs when i'll try running it from eclipse?
In case i'll put my effective project's settings. Also, the pom is very simply and the ids correspond on the ones being present in the settings.xml (otherwise it should have gave me an error even from the command line)

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>C:\Users\mmarchesi\.m2\repository</localRepository>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>***</password>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/myname_group/</url>
      <id>central</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>myname</id>
          <name>Repository for myname jar</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/myname_group/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check your Eclipse settings. `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings`. Does it point to your settings.xml?

Comment: @wirnse - thank you for the tip; indeed it was that the problem, because i moved the maven folder under programs, while it was pointing in another folder